# How to take data from a website's applications > localStorage using storage api to extension in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am pretty much new to chrome extension programming. I have a website which stores data in the localStorage tab of chrome debug tools under Applications with a key of activities. I want to access this into my custom made chrome extension and use it to download that data as a file. Please guide me. Any help is appreciated.
I am extremely confused by popup, background script, content script, etc.

P.S. The data is not stored by me, it is stored by the website I am trying to use this extension on.

Comment: Your extension's *content script* can access site's `localStorage` directly.

Comment: How do I for example console log it, I tried accessing from localStorage and console logging it but didn't work. If it did would it output to extension's consol or the website's?

Comment: Show an [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: actually the localStorage solution worked Thank You if you'd post it as a solution I could conclude this thread with an upvote to that